# History of points of view on Eisenstein series

Tags: ho.history-overview, automorphic-forms, reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures, eisenstein-series

What is the history of Eisenstein series?  Did the mathematician Eisenstein actually encounter them?

There are, as far as I know, two major perspectives on what Eisenstein series are.  The first is in the study of modular forms.  By summing over lattice points, one obtains a holomorphic modular form

$$E_{2k}(z) = \sum\limits_{(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m+nz)^{2k}}$$

for $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ which together with the cusp forms exhausts the space of modular forms of a given weight.

The other perspective is in considering a unitary representation $(\pi, V)$ of a Levi subgroup $M$ of a semisimple real Lie group $G$.  The representation considered should be left $\Gamma \cap M$- invariant for a lattice $\Gamma$ of $G$.  If $P$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G$ containing $M$ as a Levi subgroup, one forms the induced representation $\mathcal V = \operatorname{Ind}_P^G \pi$ of $G$ and, wishing to embed $\mathcal V$ into $L^2(\Gamma \backslash G)$, one associates to each $\varphi_{\pi} \in \mathcal V$ the Eisenstein series

$$E(\varphi_{\pi},g) = \sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma \cap P \backslash \Gamma \cap G} \varphi_{\pi}(\gamma g). \tag{1}$$

There is a bit more to it, as one needs to take continuous sums (integrals) of such Eisenstein series $E(\varphi_{\pi_s},g)$ for various unramified twists $\pi_s$ of $\pi$, and  analytically continue $E(\varphi_{\pi_s},g)$ so that the formula (1) no longer makes sense.

These perspectives can be connected by associating modular forms with automorphic forms on $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z) \backslash \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$.

Did these two points of view on Eisenstein series develop independently?  Who were the first people to connect them?

Comment: some aspects are discussed in https://mathoverflow.net/a/220535/11260

Comment: Surely the lattice point version came up first, and the second version out of attempts to generalize it

Comment: The first occurence was probably as the Laurent coefficients of (Weierstrass) elliptic functions at $0$, without thinking to the action of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ on the upper half plane. The modular functions parametrize complex tori so it is natural to study complex tori first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q:** *What is the history of Eisenstein series? Did the mathematician Eisenstein actually encounter them?*

**A:** Yes, he did, see [Elliptic Functions According to
Eisenstein and Kronecker](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/8714).

The reference is  [Beiträge zu Theorie der elliptischen Functionen. VI. Genaue Untersuchungen der unendlichen Doppelproducte, aus welchen die elliptischen Functionen als Quotienten zusammengesetzt sind, und der mit ihnen zusammenhangenden Doppelreihen](https://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN243919689_0035) (1847).

Eisenstein writes the double sum (on page 223) as
[image]
where $w=\alpha m+\beta n$ and the sum is over the two integers $m,n$.